# Do I need ExtJS with Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to learn Sencha Touch framework. In their website, I can see links to download Sencha Touch and ExtJS. Do I need both of them installed on my local server to get the Sencha framework up and running or do I just need Sencha Touch application? I'm confused when I should be using ExtJS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Touch, you only need Touch.

Touch is used for mobile devices. Ext is used for desktops.

Comment: Then when do I use ExtJS? Is it used for creating complex apps? Is Sencha Touch sufficient for creating simple apps?

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean the apps that are created with only Touch do not render well in desktops and need some kind of wrapper (using ExtJS) for it to work well in desktops?

Comment: They will render on modern browsers, but the point is, do you want the same interface that you're using on a phone to be the same interface that appears on a 30" monitor? Chances are, no, you don't.

Comment: Ok. I see your point. Thanks. So if I don't need to worry about the apps on desktops and am solely targeting mobile phones, then I don't need to worry about ExtJS, right? I'm just starting out with mobile development. Most likely I will get to a point where I will delve into ExtJS in detail.

Comment: I was trying out Sencha Touch yesterday. I noticed that I needed to modify ExtJS even when I had to develop for mobile devices. For instance, if I wanted to create something a slightly complex, then without modifying ExtJS, it doesn't seem possible.... unless I am not overcomplicating things....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop for the mobile platform, Sencha Touch is all you need.

Comment: See my comment above... Btw, it wasn't me who gave your answer negative... :)

Comment: Np:)

I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Sencha Touch and Ext JS are 2 different products/framweorks.

Comment: Hmm... but in the docs, there is so much about ExtJS even in the most basic app creation level: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/first_app. I'm trying to learn to create mobile apps with Sencha and from what I can see ExtJS is part of it (unless Ext and ExtJS are 2 different things).

Comment: "Ext" is just the namespace. I promise you Ext JS and Sencha Touch is 2 different products. If you want to build a Touch app, just download Sencha Touch.